# After downgrading Windows 10 to the previous build, can I return to the newer one?

Tags: windows-10, windows-update, downgrade, build

I've downgraded Windows trying to fix the problem with the start menu, but it made it even worse (previously the menu just didn't open, now it still doesn't plus I get error prompt)

---

The problem is that Windows Update shows only some Internet Explorer patches and even they won't download, as the progress is always 0%

Comment: Sure;  Just install the newer build by installing the appropriate Windows Update.

Comment: From the description of your problem it sounds like a reinstall of your current version would be better.